# Como hacer un select option en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

Necesito listar todos los 'prestadores' que estan en una base de datos en un select option en ruby on rails.
La tabla se llama 'providers' y tiene como campos 'id' y 'name'.
He intentado hacer esto en mi vista:

```
<%= form.select :provider_id, providers.pluck(:id), id: :negociacion_contacto_id %>
```

Comment: y qué has intentado?

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `collection_select`, el cual hace exactamente lo que estás buscando:

```
<%= form.collection_select :provider_id, Provider.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Cuando ejecuto lel codigo que me propusiste me dice lo siguiente: undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x00007f426d8875a0>:0x00007f426d833a18>... A que hace referencia el ':provider_id' y el ':id'. En que se diferencian?

Comment: Hay alguna manera de ordenarlos por name? y como recupero el valor seleccionado del select en el controlador para utilizarlo en el create?

Comment: @francofernandez Para ordenarlos por `name` cambia el `Provider.all` por `Provider.order(:name)` (aunque esta lógica sería mejor encapsularla en un `scope`). En el controlador solo necesitas leer el objeto `params`, el cual tiene todos los elementos de la forma que envías.

Comment: Lo realice de esta manera pero no me funciona: <%= collection_select(:provider, :id_persona, Provider.order(:fullname), :id, :fullname) %> No entiendo como recibiria en el controlador el id del provider..